# want to scrape this link with members details

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
for count in range(1,3):
    r = requests.get('http://findadentist.co.in/doctorSearch.asp?search=1&curpage=' + str(count) + '&#src')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table',class_='tableborder')
    for data in table.find('tbody'):
        for data1 in data.find_all('tr'):
            print data1.text
```

you can select state maharashtra and city mumbai

Comment: This fails to run on Python 3.6. Please provide a valid url along with your desired output.

Comment: http://findadentist.co.in - you can run this and then can select ,state maharashtra and city mumbai @ DirtyBit

Comment: The page uses a json call with form data, What details do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do POST request instead of GET request. This POST request needs four values.

For your case, values 'Maharashtra' and 'Mumbai' change into values like this. Use this code for requests and then use BeautifulSoup to parse it:

```
payload = {'cboCity': 'Mumbai',
           'cboState': '15',
           'txtChoice': 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE',
           'cboSpectility': 'All'}
url = 'http://findadentist.co.in/doctorSearch.asp?search=1&'
res = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

You can find all such data from browser devtools. Go to Devtools->Network

Comment: Its Working..Thanks bro@Kamal